# PHP/AJax Freemium Tools - How to Limit The Number of Uses Before Showing Results

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, saas

I've done some searches for this and can't seem to find anything on it. I'm looking for a starting point to create freemium model tools.

The languages that I'll be using are PHP, Ajax and MySQL.

Here's what I would like to get done.

Any random user can use the free tools on the site, but after X number of uses, they are asked to register an account, otherwise, they can't use the tool for another 24 hours.

From what I've seen from other tools, it seems to be done through IP tracking and storing them in a DB. But I can see this getting pretty messy after hitting the millions of results.

Can anyone with experience provide guidance on how I can start limiting the number of uses? I just have no idea where to start at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if they don't register with a email first then the only solution i think is IP it doesnt have to get messy if you set it up right. you just a table with column for ip column for counter and column for date and time.
then when you insert the data the same time you run another query to delete data older than 24 hours. Some guys use IP combined with device info.

Comment: Thanks for this. So I'd need a cron script to delete data older than 24 hours then right? Also, if I had multiple tools doing the same thing and it was 3 uses of each tool, then I'd just need to assign an IF function I'm guessing before the script runs, correct?

Comment: create a column  for each tool like tool1 tool2 tool3 then put  create a file check.php then in here you get the ip and put it in a variable $ip then run a query something like select '$tool' from tablename where usurip ='$ip' then count the result and put it in a variable $tempcount run a if statement to check it if the users count is less than 3 run a new query like update tablename set '$tool'='$tool' + 1 where userip = '$ip'  then elseif the user count is 3 you redirect. inside your tool code put a variable $tool='your table name for the tool' and include your check.php just after that

Comment: Thanks. Accepted your answe.r